# python - regex with quotes inside of the string

Tags: python, regex

--

Hi everyone,

I need a hand for the following regex.
The string is something like:

```
str = 'value=\"20\" />\r\n\t\r\n<\/div>","whatiwant":"<div id=\"whatiwant\">\r\n\t\r\n\t\t<\/div>","idontwanthat":"<div id=\"idontwanthat\">\r\n\t\r\n\t blablalblalblalbla \t\r\n\t\t\t<\/div>"'
```

I would like the entire div of "whatiwant".
I tried the following:

```
matches=re.findall(r'\"whatiwant\":\"(.+?)\":\"',mstr)
```

ps: i can have other div in the div.

Any help with me appreciated

Comment: An html parser would be more suitable for this. Is this really your string or a part of a web page?

Comment: Hi jerry, i know but the string is not suitable for an html parser. i will use one for the div that i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"whatiwant":"(.*?[^\\])??"
```

This will match the literal `"whatiwant":` and then anything (even an empty string) inside double quotes `""`.

If you want to extract the div's html code, you can retrieve the first group's value:

```
matches=re.findall(r'"whatiwant":"(.*?[^\\])??"', mstr)
for match in matches:
    html= match.group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) -

```
\"whatiwant\":.*(?=,\".*?\"\:)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hC2lQ4/2)